# Can't connect to MySQL database that was tunnel on ngrok service from different network

Tags: c#, mysql, ngrok

I have this C# Winforms application that contains MySQL database connection string in it, in this case I used ngrok to tunnel the server, the user should be able to insert some data from the application to the database, now I have this one problem: When I tried to connect to the database (by using command `connection.Open`) from different network I got an error saying `Timeout expired. Time timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.` on the winform application.

This is how I start the ngrok fowarding:

```
ngrok tcp 3306
```

ngrok generated this URL:

```
tcp://0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io:18649 -> localhost:3306
```

This is the connection string example (App.config):

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="CONNECTIONSETUP" connectionString="SERVER=0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io;Port=18649;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypass;" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I'm running on Windows 10 operating system turning off the firewall doesn't seem to fix the issue. This issue only occurs to devices outside my network and works fine on different devices on my network.

Comment: Define OUTSIDE you network.  Do you mean on the Internet?  The IP address need to be a public IP address to work over the Internet.  If the IP is inside a private network than you need to modify you IP masks so the two networks can communicate.  Test first with PING to make sure you have a route.

Comment: Run `Test-NetConnection 0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io -Port 18649` from the client machine. It should say `TcpTestSucceeded : True` at the end. If it doesn't, then your WinForms app won't be able to make a MySQL connection either. You'll need to fix firewall rules until that works.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger IT Does says `TcpTestSucceeded : True` on the client machine but the winforms application still refused to make a connection. "Fix firewall rules" How? do I have to make a new rules that allow connection from 3306 port or?? I'm lost

Comment: If the TCP connection worked, then it _seems_ like your WinForms app should be able to connect. What does it mean that "This issue only occurs to devices outside my network and works fine on different devices on my network."? Are you using `Server=0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io;Port=18649` in both cases? I'm not familiar with `ngrok tcp` but maybe it has some rules about IP addresses that are permitted to connect to the endpoint (so that it's not accessible by anyone on the Internet by default)?

Comment: Yes I uses that connection string for both cases. `maybe it has some rules about IP addresses that are permitted to connect to the endpoint (so that it's not accessible by anyone on the Internet by default)` I thought that's ngrok job to automatically make it possible for accessing localhost tcp/IP?